# Make a relation of these four tables

Tags: mysql, database-design

Can anyone help me out making a relation of these four tables? It's easy to see but it's hard to make a relation table.

[image]

Here's the layout of my SQL structure:

[image]

It's my task to guess the relation of the `sub_category`, `action`, and `item_description`.

I already tried:

```
category <- sub_category <- action <- item_description
```

...but it did not work. Every sub category here has a different action, that's why it's hard to analyze. For example, if you click the Patio Covers in the sub category it will only show remove and repair in the action. Imagine you clicked the the Patio Covers then another action will appear, also another item description will appear. How you will elaborate the connection of the `sub_category`, `action`, and `item_description`?

Let's assume that the id of the Awnings is 1. The real problem here is when querying. For example if I click the Awnings in the category

```
SELECT * FROM action where sub_cat_id=1
```

What if I click the Patio Covers? Patio Covers have only two options in the action, which is remove and repair only. Assume that we have a `sub_cat_id` in the Action table.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try bridging tables to connect them.

Add a `fieldID` from one table and then add another `fieldID` from another table into a new table `X`. There needs to be some sort of relationship between the tables. So if you have additional tables besides what you mentioned that can help you with this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add sub_id to the action table, and act_id to the item_description table. Then you will be able to join them.

Comment: Perhaps when you click on "Patio Covers" you will "select * from action where sub_cat_id = 2" ?   In case "Patio Covers" sub_id = 2.